# How to see value of struct inside another struct

Tags: c, struct

I have a struct:

```
typedef struct {
  scalar_t x;   
  scalar_t y;
  scalar_t z;
 } vector_t;
```

and

```
typedef struct {
      scalar_t x;   
      scalar_t y;
      scalar_t z;
     } point_t;
```

inside of a struct:

```
typedef struct {
    char *name;
    int lives;
    point_t pos; /* current position */
    vector_t vel; /* current velocity */
    .
    .
    .
    int score; /* players' score */
    .
    .
    .
    } player_data_t;
```

Inside of a function, I have logic that calculates player position. But, now when I want to see values of x, y and z. When I try `printf("%d", plyr->pos.x)` or any other value, all I get is 7's. So, I must have get it somewhere wrong because, player is moving. He is not on pos (7,7,7) all the time.

Comment: You seem to have posted the definition for vector_t twice...

Comment: Also, it's impossible to say what the issue might be currently. Please post a complete test-case that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Also, `scalar_t` seems to be containing itself.

Comment: Sory, I meant point_t. Not a scalar_t

Comment: your code is a complete mess. after you edited it, it became more horrible...

Comment: What type is `scalar_t` ? Perhaps a `double`?

Comment: @UttamMalakar And just what is so messy about it, except the indention? typdef'd structs are utterly common and a fundamental part of the C language.

Comment: Yes it is a double! OK, now I'm getting right values! Thanks, @ilmo-euro ! Thanks a lot!

Comment: how did you initialize the values. Please show us some CODE.

Comment: @peter-miehle
 `plyr->pos.x = start_pt.x;`
 `plyr->pos.z = start_pt.y;`

 `plyr->vel = make_vector(0, 0, 0);`

 `set_view_mode(plyr, ABOVE);`
 `update_view(plyr, EPS);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comments, `scalar_t` is in fact a `double`, so
`printf("%d")` interpreted it wrong. A good idea would be bundling
`scalar_t` with a function to print out its value,
or at least a constant containing the proper `printf` format specifier.
That way the flexibility of `typedef`ing won't be lost. For example:

```
#define SCALAR_SPECIFIER "%d"
typedef double scalar_t;
...
scalar_t foo;
printf("Value of foo: " SCALAR_SPECIFIER, foo);
```

or

```
typedef double scalar_t;
void print_scalar_t(scalar_t value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an example

```
player_data_t foo;

foo.pos.x = 10.;

printf ("%lf\n", foo.pos.x);
```

Comment: Yes, when I try like that, compiler reports an error: request for member 'pos' in something not a structure or union

plyr is a pointer

Comment: @Miller `foo->pos` means that foo is a pointer, it is the very same thing as writing `(*foo).pos`. And of course if foo is not a pointer, you should do as demonstrated in this answer.